# Error al abrir fichero para comprobar instalación

Tags: php, laravel

¿Por qué a la hora que llamo el localhost para corroborar la instalación me aparece lo siguiente?

> Warning:
>   require(C:\xamppnew\htdocs\findumentaria\public/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xamppnew\htdocs\findumentaria\public\index.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xamppnew\htdocs\findumentaria\public/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xamppnew\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xamppnew\htdocs\findumentaria\public\index.php on line
>   24

La línea 24 en mi código es la siguiente:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Como se puede ver en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: amigo pero es un proyecto propio? o un repositorio? intenta ingresar composer install

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) para encontrar consejos sobre cómo mejorar y dar formato a tus preguntas

Answer (score 0):

Esta intentando cargar el autoload pero no lo encuentra si sigues la ruta lo veras `_DIR_` llega hasta el index `../vendor/autoload.php` esta saliendose a la carpeta padre he intentando acceder a vendor pero no esta, en resumen vendor no esta en la raiz de tu proyecto por eso te da ese error

Comment: Que tal Gracias lo reviso Gamboa YGB

Answer (score 0):

En la estructura de carpetas del proyecto se puede ver que no existe la carpeta vendor, por lo cual debes ejecutar `composer install` desde la línea de comandos a partir del directorio raíz de tu proyecto.  El archivo vendor/autoload.php es generado una vez se descarguen las dependencias con composer.